# Nginx Upstream Not Serving Up Go Server

Tags: docker, go, nginx

I am trying to hit a Go chat server through an Nginx proxy, but the Nginx upstream does not seem to be working.  It does serve up my client just fine (a React app) but I can not seem to hit the Go server (chat). I am new to using Nginx, do you see a missing config or something?  The upstreams are all separate Docker containers.

```
upstream client {
  server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
  server api:7777;
}

upstream chat {
  server chat:9000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location /chat {
    proxy_pass http://chat;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
  }

  location /sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://client;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }

  location /oracle {
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }

  location /api/payment {
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }

  location /signin {
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }

  location /register {
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you reach chat:900 via curl on the nginx container/vm ?

Comment: @gipsy I get same thing I get when I hit it in browser: 404 page not found

Comment: Show your server code.

Comment: @ConorBurke So that seems to be the problem , debug that first. Try a simple server first and make it work.

Comment: Server code was messed up, incorrect function call.  Thanks for your help @gipsy